# Invite friends to facebook app (not a game) preferably using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-invite

I'm wondering if it is possible to allow a user to invite friends to join my app, even though it is registered as a fitness app and not a game through facebook. Does this even matter?

I'd like to use the facebook requests dialog, but I am being tripped up by the wording in the info section of this page: http://goo.gl/zfx4R where it says that the request dialog is only available to games on facebook.com.

If the requests dialog is not the answer, how should I go about allowing a user to invite their friends? If there is a PHP solution I'd prefer it.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there are no features which are restricted to the "type" of app, so game versus app should make no difference.

You can open the FB.ui({method: 'apprequests'}) Facebook Javascript dialog on any web page, the app doesn't need to be in a canvas or page tab. The wording may be confusing, but what is meant is that, when a user does accept an invitation, they will be sent to the app canvas.

This means that you will need to configure your Facebook app to have a namespace (`apps.facebook.com/<namespace>`) and you will need to handle users coming from invitations at that point. What you do with them afterwards is up to you, you could redirect them to your website if you wish.

You should be aware that the Facebook Requests process is deliberately quite cryptic to avoid gaining information from users who don't want to be involved in your app. Unless you have a specific reason to track invitations, I suggest using the FB.ui({ method: 'feed'}) dialog with a target_id.

Because of this, there isn't and will not be a way in PHP to perform this. You will need to load the JS SDK onto your page and invoke the dialog, then allow the user to make their decision (whether using the 'feed' or 'apprequests' dialog).